# Pattern for ViewController that can show as TableViewController or CollectionViewController

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, design-patterns, uicollectionview

In my app(s) I have a ViewController that will show content as a `UITableViewController` on iPhone and a `UICollectionViewController` on iPad and I'd like to have a single `MYContentViewController` that shows the correct ViewController respectively.  **This is an ideal situation for Multiple Inheritance** where I'd have a `MYContentTableViewController` and `MYContentCollectionViewController` each of which inherit from `UITable/CollectionViewController` AND `MYContentViewController` but obviously Cocoa doesn't support Multiple Inheritance so what is the best solution?

Also, I don't want to just have a `MyContentViewController` with a `UITableView` or `UICollectionView` because as of iOS7 you get snazzy transitions if you use an *actual* UICollectionViewController.

**Currently I'm thinking using Protocols and a 'ParentViewController' is the best way to go** but I'd love it if there were a way to not involve a 'ParentViewController' with `addChildViewController`:

```
@protocol MYContentViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
@end

@protocol MYContentViewControllerDataSource <NSObject>
- (MYDataProvider *)dataProviderForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
- (NSInteger)numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
- (NSInteger)numberOfSections;
@end

@protocol MYContentViewController <NSObject>
- (void)reloadData;
- (void)reloadSections:(NSIndexSet *)sections;
- (void)reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths;
- (void)deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths;
- (void)insertItemsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths;

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <MYContentViewControllerDataSource> dataSource;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <MYContentViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

`MyContentViewController` would implement the dataSource and delegate so it would provide all the data and act on all the interactions for the Collection and Table and own any interactions for the 'parent' view controller (like navigation button interactions).  And `MyContentViewController` would `addChildViewController` for the Table and Collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I'd try is to think of a `UITableView` as an easily emulated special case of `UICollectionView`, with a vertical layout and full width cells.

Then you can use just a regular `UICollectionViewController` with two layouts and cell types.  One of the layouts/cell types can be designed to imitate a `UITableView/UITableViewCell`.

Comment: Ah, interesting suggestion, I'll try this out and see if I run into any issues!